# How to grant WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission in android rooted oreo

Tags: android, apn

I can programmatically set, add, updated, delete APN in android 4.2.2 easily , but above android 6 I could not be able to grant `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` permission using runtime permission in rooted device as a system app.
Thanks for any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use runtime permission check if run app above 6.1 have look

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //requesting permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS}, 1);
        } else
            //permission is granted      

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //permission granted by user
                } else
                    //permission denied by user               
            }         

        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Did you try this code? I used this runtime permission, but runtime permission can not show any dialog for WRITE_APN_SETTINGS. And that's why I asked this question. And this permission is only for system app. You have to test it on rooted device. I need workaround for android oreo.

Comment: yes this will not show dialog because its only for system app.

Comment: yes, but when I install the app as a system app with that runtime permission, the state of the permission always remains ungranted.